Problems understanding tkinter.Tk.wait_variable()
I'm writing a blackjack-program where the user decides 1 out of 4 actions using buttons on the screen. Each button sets the action-variable to another number, based on it's state the program continues appropriately.
As I understood, Tk.wait_variable(action) is supposed to make Tk wait until the variable changes, or in my case until one of the buttons is clicked. I can't get it working properly though and keep receiving the following error: **_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "tkwait variable|visibility|window name"
I couldn't find any resources to explain what this error-code means and what I'm supposed to change. The GUI and the buttons work properly and change the value of self.action.
Here the (abbreviated) code. The forth function "def play_hand" is relevant.
class CardsGui():

    def __init__(self, game):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.blackjack()
        self.window.mainloop()


    def set_action(self, action):
        print(action)
        self.action = action


    def blackjack(self):

        self.action_buttons = []
        button_split = Button(text="Stand", command=lambda: self.set_action(3), width=10)
        button_split.grid(column=1, row=9, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.action_buttons.append(button_split)
        
        hand = self.bj_play_hand(player_number, player)


    def play_hand(self, player_number, hand, AI=False):

        self.display_hand(player_number, hand)
        self.action = None
        self.window.wait_variable(self.action)

        if self.action == 0:
            print("Stand")
        elif self.action == 1:
            print("Hit")
        elif self.action == 2:
            print("Double")
        elif self.action == 3:
            print("Split")


It expects a tk.Variable not a python variable. Note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74370984/13629335

Do you have BooleanVar() or StringVar() on it?
